# Cassandra solr integration with dataimporthandler using CQL Driver . Getting Frame size larger than max length (16384000)!

Tags: jdbc, solr, cassandra, dataimporthandler, data-import

I am trying to use dataimporthandler to integrate cassandra and solr using org.apache.cassandra.cql.jdbc.CassandraDriver .

I am able to fetch 20000 rows but it tried to fetch all rows its showing  "Caused by: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: Frame size (16402604) larger than max length (16384000)!"

My data-config file :

```
    <dataConfig>
 <dataSource autoCommit="true" driver="org.apache.cassandra.cql.jdbc.CassandraDriver" url="jdbc:cassandra://127.0.0.1/test_new"   />
 <document name="products">
 <entity name="testproducts" query="select * from products LIMIT 20015">
     <field name="id" column="product_id"/>
         <field name="productId" column="product_id"/>
         <field name="productPrice" column="sale_price" />
          <field name="productSource" column="source"/>
     <field name="productMrpPrice" column="mrp_price"/>
              <entity name="productrating" query="select * from product_reviews where product_id='${testproducts.product_id}'">
                <field name="productRating" column="rating" />
                <field name="productReview" column="review" />
                <field name="customerId" column="customer_id" />
                <field name="customerName" column="customer_name" />
            </entity>
  </entity>

  </document>
</dataConfig>
```

How to maximze framesize in cql jdbc driver class?
How to import all rows using cql jdbc  driver ?

Comment: Which jar file you are using? What is the version of Solr and Cassandra?